# Запятая при однородных членах: “серьезный (,)обстоятельный разговор"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены

Нужна ли запятая: Состоялся серьезный (,)обстоятельный разговор по ряду вопросов...

Comment: @Верьясова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Нужна. ================

Answer (score 2):

Запятая нужна. Это однородные определения. Между ними можно вставить союз ''и".

> Состоялся серьезный и обстоятельный разговор по ряду вопросов...

Comment: Я очень благодарна Вам за ответы. Спасибо.